# Regular expression for (=string)

Tags: python, regex, string, search, match

I have a text file including thousands of lines. here's an example

```
line = .Falies/367. 11DG1550/11DG15537.Axiom=nt60
line = .Failies/367. 11DG1550/11DG15537.Axiom=nt50
```

I tried to extract the string at the end 'nt60', 'nt50'.

```
lines = line.split('=')
version = lines[-1]
```

the problem is that the end of line character will be included (`'\n'`)

I thought of using regular expression search to match the string starting from (`'=nt'`)
but I have no idea what shall I use to match a `=, word, number`.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex to match  a `=` `nt` then a `number` is:

```
=(nt\d+)
```

And in your example:

```
line = .Falies/367. 11DG1550/11DG15537.Axiom=nt60 
line = .Failies/367. 11DG1550/11DG15537.Axiom=nt50
```

it will return two matches:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [49-53] `nt60`
MATCH 2
1.  [105-109] `nt50`
```

Explanation:

```
`=` matches the character `=` literally 
1st Capturing group `(nt\d+)`
   `nt` matches the characters `nt` literally (case sensitive)  
   `\d` match a digit `[0-9]`  
   `+` Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible,  
       giving back as needed
```

if you want your regex to match a = `word` `number` then just replace the `nt` with `\w+` to match any word.

hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @unixer. I found it a little bit complicated but it helps anyway.

Comment: no problem @MarJamil, choose whatever suits your needs :)

Comment: @MarJamil preferable way to say thanks @ SO is [vote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)

Comment: You are right Grijesh I meant no offence it's really helpful but somehow complicated for my level. I'm sure that I'm gonna use it in further stage when my programming skills get better. Thank you @unixer :)

Comment: Great answer, but, regular expressions may be a bit of an overkill here since the OP knows where to look for in the string, an `rsplit` would be better.

Comment: @Sukrit Kalra, the question was literally: I thought of using regular expression search to match the string starting from ('=nt') but I have no idea what shall I use to match a =, word, number.Can anyone help?

Comment: Yes, I know. Hence, the right answer. Just mentioning that an `rsplit` would be faster and hence, better.

Answer (score 2):

Your first approach is absolutely fine. You can just use the string that you have extracted using your first method and then apply `strip()` to it:

`strip()` removes all leading and trailing whitespaces and newlines from a string.

```
>>> your_str = 'nt60\n'
>>> your_str.strip()
'nt60'
```

For your case:

```
lines = line.rsplit('=',1)
version = lines[-1].strip()
```

Comment: Doesn't use `string` (is a module)  and `str` (is a type) as variable name.

Comment: You should use `rsplit('=', 1)`. Would probably become faster if you have a big file.

Comment: @SukritKalra, THank you for that addition, Updated accordingly